# fscanf stops reading file without any reason

Tags: c, scanf

I am writing a little program for reading a file formatted like that :

```
2 2
1.0 2.0
5.0 5.1
6.5 3.1
5.1 2.3
3 1
4 1 2 3 5 2
1 4 5 2 6 5
1 4 5 2 3 6
```

I am using fscanf to read the first two integers and allocate an array to store all four float that follows. It works fine. But when the "cursor" arrives to the line that contains integers "3 1", it stops working for any reason...

```
float *c = NULL;
float **coord = NULL;
f = fopen("mesh.dat", "r");
if( f != NULL ){
    /* the first two integers */
    fscanf(f, "%d %d", &n1, &n2);
    n = n1*n2;
    c = malloc(2*n*sizeof(float));
    coord = malloc(2*sizeof(float *));
    for(i=0; i<2; i++){ coord[i] = &c[i*n1]; }

    /* reading all coordinates */
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){ fscanf(f, "%f %f", &coord[0][i], &coord[1][i]); }

    /* reading the two integers */
    fscanf(f, "%d %d", &n, &t);
    printf("n = %d, t = %d\n", n, t);
}
fclose(f);
```

The program stops here. Because it doesn't read the integers "3 1".

Any idea ?? I'm tearing out my hair trying to understand...

Comment: There is a reason, you are misusing it. Also the code you posted doesn't allow to explain what's wrong. And what exactly you mean `stops reading`...?

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try to explain the problem with more code

Comment: You read values into n1 and n2 then multiply n by 2.  Please post a working program not a poorly formed fragment to avoid wasting the time of people who are willing to help.

Comment: Yes, I updated the code I wrote. Actually, n=n1*n2. Sorry for missed that.

Comment: Need to post the declaration of `c`, else `&c[i*n1]` is suspect.

Comment: Could you please try to provide a _minimal, compilable example that still exhibits the behaviour you are asking about_? Because when I add code to make this a complete program, it works and reads 3 and 1 as expected. It seems likely that the problem is in the part of the program that you are not showing. That is why you should always try to include a complete program.

Comment: Also, check that the "mesh.dat" file doesn't contain any garbage characters that are not showing up in what you copied here.

Comment: Yes I finally found where was the mistake. I didn't pasted all the code because there is more than 250 lines. The mistake was that I used 2 functions to create the "mesh.dat" file. And after that, I used another one for reading the file. But I forgot to use "fclose(file)" in the functions I used to generate "mesh.dat"... Thanks to everyone !

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
fscanf(f, "%d %d", &n1, n2);
```

Should be

```
fscanf(f, "%d %d", &n1, &n2);
```

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake when I copy / pasted the code here. In my program it's okay. But thanks anyway :)